# Issue in overlapping of items in hoverable dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a hoverable dropdown menu and the items of the dropdown are overlapped. I don't know how the CSS should be, but I tried to modify each class, but still doesn't work.

I also tried to modify the display of links, but that doesn't work. Here is the code I made:

```
<style>
#menu
{
   margin:0;
   font-size: 30px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid;
   text-align: center;
}

#menu a
{
   color:#900;
   text-decoration:none;
}

#menu .subitem a{
   display: block;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   z-index: 1;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

#menu a:hover
{
   text-decoration:underline;
}

.item{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   border-right: 0.5px solid;
   padding-right: 30px;
   padding-left: 30px;
}

.subitem{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menu .item:hover .subitem{
    display: block;
}
</style>
<div id="navWrapper">
      <ul id="menu">
         <li class="item"><a href="#">Small Things</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Gnomes</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Fairies</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Elves</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Leprechauns</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="item"><a href="#">Big Things</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Loch Ness Monster</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Ogres</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Giants</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Dragons</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>

      </ul>
  </div>
```

I want to display properly each item when I hover with the mouse like it is in this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLqs8.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confused your `.submenu` with `.subitem`:

```css
#menu
{
   margin:0;
   font-size: 30px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid;
   text-align: center;
}

#menu a
{
   color:#900;
   text-decoration:none;
}

#menu .subitem a{
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

#menu a:hover
{
   text-decoration:underline;
}

.item{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   border-right: 0.5px solid;
   padding-right: 30px;
   padding-left: 30px;
}

.subitem {
  /* display: none; <- get rid of that */
  /* position: absolute; <- get rid of that, otherwise all your subitems will be in the top left corner */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute; /* <- put it here */
  display: none; /* <- put it here */
  list-style-type: none;
  left:-40px;
  top: 30px;
}

#menu .item:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navWrapper">
      <ul id="menu">
      
         <li class="item"><a href="#">Small Things</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Gnomes</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Fairies</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Elves</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Leprechauns</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         
         <li class="item"><a href="#">Big Things</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Loch Ness Monster</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Ogres</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Giants</a></li>
               <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Dragons</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>

      </ul>
  </div>
```